# Mysql get the users which didn't have any messages to a certain user?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following `messages` table
[image]

I managed to get the users that have messages with a certain user using this query in php

```
SELECT ReceiverUserId,SenderUserId,Name,Email,
    Count(CASE WHEN IsReaded = 0 THEN 1 END) AS messagesNum,
    Message,MessageDateTime 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM messages 
      ORDER BY MessageDateTime DESC) AS footbl
JOIN users ON users.id =footbl.SenderUserId
WHERE ReceiverUserId=".$user_id." 
GROUP BY SenderUserId
```

It returned the users that have messages with a certain user ($user_id)
but it didn't return the users that the certain user send them messages with out any replies from them, I tried another query for this purpose

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` as m
    join `users` on m.`ReceiverUserId`=`users`.Id
    WHERE (select count(*) from `messages` as s
    WHERE m.`SenderUserId`=s.`ReceiverUserId` ) = 0
    AND `SenderUserId`=".$user_id.
    " group by `SenderUserId`
```

For Example if I have the following data
 [image]

The first query (if $user_id=2) returns the following result:

[image]

The second query (if $user_id=2) returns nothing

How Should I know that 2 send messages to 4 and 5 too?

Comment: where ReceiverUserId=".$receiver_user_id" or SenderUserId=".$receiver_user_id"

Comment: try left join Instead of join

Comment: On a side point, consider changing `IsReaded` to `IsRead` as that is how it should be.

Comment: Could you provide user table and your expected result? that really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question so that you want to get all user IDs of the users who contacted a certain user `$user_id`, i.e. wrote messages to or received messages from him/her.

First, let's get all IDs of users who received messages from `$user_id`.

```
SELECT ReceiverUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE SenderUserId = $user_id
```

Then we want all IDs of users who sent messages to `$user_id`.

```
SELECT SenderUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE ReceiverUserId = $user_id
```

Now we want to combine the 2 results.

```
SELECT ReceiverUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE SenderUserId = $user_id
UNION
SELECT SenderUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE ReceiverUserId = $user_id
```

Duplicate rows are removed by default by [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

The above query should return the following result for `$user_id = 2`:

```
| ContactId |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         3 |
|         4 |
|         5 |
+-----------+
```

If you want the IDs of the users who did *not* have contact to a certain user, you can use the result of above query inside another query:

```
SELECT Id
FROM users
WHERE Id NOT IN(
    SELECT ReceiverUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE SenderUserId = $user_id
    UNION
    SELECT SenderUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE ReceiverUserId = $user_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks that a good answer, but what if I want the messageNum and the last message of each user, I tried the following `SELECT users.Id,ReceiverUserId,SenderUserId,Name,Email,Count(CASE WHEN IsReaded = 0 THEN 1 END) as messagesNum,Message,MessageDateTime
FROM users,messages
WHERE users.Id NOT IN(
    SELECT ReceiverUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE SenderUserId = 2
    UNION
    SELECT SenderUserId AS ContactId FROM messages WHERE ReceiverUserId = 2
)` but it didn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
    FROM Users u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Messages
                          WHERE ReceiverUserId = u.id
                            AND SenderUserId = 1234 )
```

Beneficial:

```
Messages:  INDEX(SenderUserId, ReceiverUserId)  -- in either order
```

(Not knowing the semantics for `Is...`, I did not throw them in.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a `NOT EXISTS` subquery to make your expect.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m INNER JOIN users u 
ON m.ReceiverUserId = u.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM messages t1
   WHERE  
      m.SenderUserID = t1.ReceiverUserId 
   AND
      m.ReceiverUserId = t1.SenderUserID
) AND 
m.SenderUserID = $user_id
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/104dae/24